# Проверка на нажатие одновременно нескольких кнопок в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе на WPF на форме у меня есть изображение челюсти (элемент Image) и на каждом зубе элемент Button.

Если нажать на зуб (то есть выделить его), то надо менять цвет кнопки с зеленого на красный. Тут все просто.

Есть два вопроса:

1) Как проверить, если пользователь нажал на область вне кнопок, чтобы снять выделение и сделать кнопку снова зеленой?

2) Как проверить, что были выделены несколько зубов (зажав Ctrl), чтобы затем все выделенные сделать красными?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для области вне кнопок установите обработчик `MouseDown`. Не забудьте установить `Background` в нечто ненулевое (хотя бы в `Transparent`).
2. Проще всего в обработчике нажатия проверить состояние клавиш мыши.

Хотя если вам такое нужно, может, вам нужен кастомный `ListView`?

Comment: Получилось, спасибо

Comment: @dmitrykozyr: Пожалуйста!